# MongoDB: Update a field of an item in array with matching another field of that item

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a data structure like this:
We have some `centers`. A `center` has some `switches`. A `switch` has some `ports`.

```
    {
     "_id" : ObjectId("561ad881755a021904c00fb5"),
     "Name" : "center1",
     "Switches" : [
        {
            "Ports" : [
                {
                    "PortNumber" : 2,
                    "Status" : "Empty"
                },
                {
                    "PortNumber" : 5,
                    "Status" : "Used"
                },
                {
                    "PortNumber" : 7,
                    "Status" : "Used"
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

All I want is to write an Update query to change the `Status` of the port that it's `PortNumber` is 5 to "Empty".
I can update it when I know the array index of the port (here array index is 1) with this query:

```
db.colection.update(
    // query
    {
        _id: ObjectId("561ad881755a021904c00fb5")
    },
    // update 
    {
        $set : { "Switches.0.Ports.1.Status" : "Empty" }
    }
);
```

But I don't know the array index of that Port.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6):

You would normally do this using the positional operator `$`, as described in the answer to this question:

[Update field in exact element array in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432677/update-field-in-exact-element-array-in-mongodb)

Unfortunately, right now the positional operator only supports one array level deep of matching.

There is a JIRA ticket for the sort of behavior that you want: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

In case you can make `Switches` into an object instead, you could do something like this:

```js
db.colection.update(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("561ad881755a021904c00fb5"),
        "Switch.Ports.PortNumber": 5
    }, 
    {
        $set: {
            "Switch.Ports.$.Status": "Empty"
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that I have to flatten my data structure into multiple collections.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know the array index of the Port, I would suggest you dynamically create the **`$set`** conditions on the fly i.e. something which would help you get the indexes for the objects and then modify accordingly, then consider using **[MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)**.

Currently this seems to be not possible using the aggregation framework. There is an unresolved open **[JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831)** linked to it. However, a workaround is possible with **[MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)**. The basic idea with MapReduce is that it uses JavaScript as its query language but this tends to be fairly slower than the aggregation framework and should not be used for real-time data analysis.

In your MapReduce operation, you need to define a couple of steps i.e. the mapping step (which maps an operation into every document in the collection, and the operation can either do nothing or emit some object with keys and projected values) and reducing step (which takes the list of emitted values and reduces it to a single element).

For the map step, you ideally would want to get for every document in the collection, the index for each `Switches` and `Ports` array fields and another key that contains the `$set` keys.

Your reduce step would be a function (which does nothing) simply defined as `var reduce = function() {};`

The final step in your MapReduce operation will then create a separate collection Switches that contains the emitted Switches array object along with a field with the `$set` conditions. This collection can be updated periodically when you run the MapReduce operation on the original collection.
Altogether, this MapReduce method would look like:

```
var map = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.Switches.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < this.Switches[i].Ports.length; j++){
            emit( 
                {
                    "_id": this._id, 
                    "switch_index": i, 
                    "port_index": j 
                }, 
                {
                    "index": j, 
                    "Switches": this.Switches[i],  
                    "Port": this.Switches[i].Ports[j],                      
                    "update": {
                        "PortNumber": "Switches." + i.toString() + ".Ports." + j.toString() + ".PortNumber",
                        "Status": "Switches." + i.toString() + ".Ports." + j.toString() + ".Status"
                    }                    
                }
            );
        }            
    }
};

var reduce = function(){};

db.centers.mapReduce(
    map,
    reduce,
    {
        "out": {
            "replace": "switches"
        }
    }
);
```

Querying the output collection `Switches` from the MapReduce operation will typically give you the result:

```
db.switches.findOne()
```

**Sample Output**:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("561ad881755a021904c00fb5"),
        "switch_index" : 0,
        "port_index" : 1
    },
    "value" : {
        "index" : 1,
        "Switches" : {
            "Ports" : [ 
                {
                    "PortNumber" : 2,
                    "Status" : "Empty"
                }, 
                {
                    "PortNumber" : 5,
                    "Status" : "Used"
                }, 
                {
                    "PortNumber" : 7,
                    "Status" : "Used"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Port" : {
            "PortNumber" : 5,
            "Status" : "Used"
        },
        "update" : {
            "PortNumber" : "Switches.0.Ports.1.PortNumber",
            "Status" : "Switches.0.Ports.1.Status"
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use the cursor from the `db.switches.find()` method to iterate over and update your collection accordingly:

```
var newStatus = "Empty";
var cur = db.switches.find({ "value.Port.PortNumber": 5 });     

// Iterate through results and update using the update query object set dynamically by using the array-index syntax.
while (cur.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cur.next();
    var update = { "$set": {} };
    // set the update query object
    update["$set"][doc.value.update.Status] = newStatus;

    db.centers.update(
        {
            "_id": doc._id._id, 
            "Switches.Ports.PortNumber": 5
        }, 
        update 
    );      
};
```

Comment: Thanks for great explanations. I think in my project situation, the best solution for me is to flatten the data structure. But your solution is also complete and good for some cases.

Comment: @Aliaaa No worries. Yes, I concur flattening your data would go a long way in solving most of the complex deeply nested array updates that MongoDB struggles to handle pressently with atomic operations.

Comment: Now this issue is fixed. use arrayFilters check https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831