# Setting the field of an arrayFilter match to the value of another field

Tags: mongodb

***Note:** This is **not** related to questions asking for [how to update a field value to another field's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171078/mongodb-update-a-field-of-an-item-in-array-with-matching-another-field-of-that), because those do not include array filter matches.*

I have the following query:

```js
db.UserNotifications.updateOne(
    {_id:ObjectId("5c5c39e94c9d4404d4577e94")}, 
    {$set:{
        "Notifications.$[match].Group.ActualUnreadCount": 50,
        "Notifications.$[match].Group.UnreadCountSnapshot": "Notifications.$[match].Group.ActualUnreadCount"
    }},
    {arrayFilters:[{
        "match.Group.Id": "some-id"
    }]});
```

Now, what I wanted to do with this is set the value of `UnreadCountSnapshot` for the match in the array, to the value of the `ActualUnreadCount` of the same match.

Instead, `UnreadCountSnapshot` just gets set to the string `"Notifications.$[match].Group.ActualUnreadCount"`.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Here's a sample document in the collection:

```js
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c5c39e94c9d4404d4577e94"
    },
    "Notifications": [{
        "Object": {
            "_id": "5e3967cc9fc5720001d7100f",
            "Type": "Transaction"
        },
        "Change": {
            "Verb": "Create",
            "TimeUtc": {
                "$date": "2020-02-04T12:47:08.796Z"
            },
            "Actors": []
        },
        "Group": {
            "TotalCount": 2,
            "ActualUnreadCount": 50,
            "UnreadCountSnapshot": 23,
            "ReadTimeUtc": {
                "$date": "2020-08-26T10:24:32.602Z"
            },
            "ViewTimeUtc": {
                "$date": "2020-08-26T10:24:32.602Z"
            }
        }
    }],
    "LastNotificationTimeUtc": {
        "$date": "2019-02-21T10:18:57.456Z"
    },
    "LastDeletedNotificationTimeUtc": {
        "$date": "2020-08-26T10:24:30.374Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arrayFields` can not allow to assign any reference field value to another field, You can use [update document with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) from MongoDB v4.2,

```
db.UserNotifications.updateOne(
  { _id: ObjectId("5c5c39e94c9d4404d4577e94") },
  [{
    $set: {
      Notifications: {
        $map: {
          input: "$Notifications",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [{
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.Object._id",
                      "5e3967cc9fc5720001d7100f" // some id
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    Group: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$this.Group",
                        {
                          ActualUnreadCount: 50, // add update number
                          UnreadCountSnapshot: "$$this.Group.ActualUnreadCount"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-iGmwIrtkbh)