# Updating object inside an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an object with an array of objects like that:

```
//restMenuType({_id: 'abcde', hasItems: [{itemId: 'a', sortId: 1}, {itemId: 'b', sortId: 2}]})
```

I am trying to replace the sortId key on both objects:

```
'replaceItemsPositionUp': function(typeId, prevId, curId, prevSortId, curSortId){
        RestMenuTypes.update({
            _id: typeId,
            hasItems: {$elemMatch: {itemId: curId}}},
            {$set: {'hasItems.sortId': prevSortId}}
        );
        RestMenuTypes.update({
                _id: typeId,
                hasItems: {$elemMatch: {itemId: prevId}}},
            {$set: {'hasItems.sortId': curSortId}}
        );

    }
```

What is thee right way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: it looks good, what is the problem here ?

Comment: I get a generic error 500.

Comment: can you give me the input and the document ?

Answer (score 2):

That's the way to do it:
Found it here:
[Update field in exact element array in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432677/update-field-in-exact-element-array-in-mongodb)

```
RestMenuTypes.update({
            _id: typeId,
            'hasItems.itemId': curId},
            {$set: { "hasItems.$.sortId": prevSortId}}
        );
        return RestMenuTypes.update({
                _id: typeId,
                'hasItems.itemId': prevId},
            {$set: {'hasItems.$.sortId': curSortId}}
        );
```