# Find and Update Inner Array - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5a99553c1b4a1b0922039e73"
},
"date_added": {
    "$date": "2018-03-02T13:42:36.684Z"
},
"title": "Black Panther",
"__v": 14,
"alls": [
    {
        "name": "Mbezi",
        "geocoordinates": "-6.8140361,39.2775983",
        "region": "Dar es salaam",
        "times": "",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5a9c74885980731a35a013b2"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "DFM",
        "geocoordinates": "-6.7726935,39.2196418",
        "region": "Dar es salaam",
        "times": "",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5a9c7f61bb57291a81d8309e"
        }
    }
]
```

}

How can i find alls name equals to "Mbezi" and update times to a certain value? Any links that can help me will be appreciated..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update field in exact element array in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432677/update-field-in-exact-element-array-in-mongodb)

Comment: Try `db.col.update(
    {"alls.name": "Mbezi"}, 
    {$set: {
        "alls.$.times": new time
    }}`