# Delete specific value from Embedded document using Mongoengine when in Embedded Document List Field

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine, listfield, embedded-documents

I have a two classes in **Mongoengine** that looks like that:

```
class User(Document):

user_id = StringField(required=True)
date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
profile_link = URLField()
email = EmailField()
first_name = StringField()
last_name = StringField()
profile_image_metadata = EmbeddedDocumentListField(ImageMetadata)
meta = {'allow_inheritance': True,
        'index_background': True,
        'collection': 'users',
        'indexes': [{'fields': ['+user_id']}]
        }

class ImageMetadata(EmbeddedDocument):
"""
"""
img_url = URLField(unique=True)
img_content = BinaryField()
img_height = IntField(min_value=0)
img_width = IntField(min_value=0)
datetime = DateTimeField(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

So, I have the **ImageMetadata** class which is an **Embedded document** in an **EmbeddedDocumentListField**.

What I want to do is to get into the User's EmbeddedDocument list and delete for every ImageMetadata document the **value** of the **img_content** key.

So after the deletion, we will have all the metadata except those of the **image_content**

What I have tried is this:

```
User.objects(user_id=some_random_id).update_one(__raw__={
    '$pull': {'profile_image_metadata': {'img_content': {'$ne': None}}}})
```

But this deleted the whole ImageMetadata object from the list, not the img_content value.

Comment: You want to remove the `img_content` key? as in `{ img_content: "somethingBinary", img_url: "somePath" }` to just `{ img_url: "somePath" }`? Abstracting there because I don't want to write the whole thing of course. You can do that with a `__raw__` argument, **however** MongoEngine itself will complain loudly because the model is different to that. So if you remove the field from the documents in the collection, the model needs to change as well. I think. It's been a while, but if memory serves it does not like it. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I want to delete the value from the given key. Not the key itself.

Comment: Okay. You want `$set` with a positional `$` operator then.  Another thing that never got fixed with mongoengine so still stick with the raw operation. Since it's in an array you need the "query" portion to match the array element you want to update. See [Update field in exact element array in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10432677/2313887). You'll want to `$set` to "empty" `BinaryContent`. You should have the helper from pymongo already in your code somewhere if you were setting content for that field before.

Comment: I used
User.objects(user_id=some_random_id).update_one(__raw__={
    '$set': {'profile_image_metadata': {'img_content': None}}}) 
and the result was to **delete every other key except** the img_content which had the value 'null'. 

So dropped everything except the key 'img_content'

Comment: You need to actually "read the link" you were given It shows how to update the matched element. The statement you just ran of course overwrites the array because that's what you are telling it to do. Read the link and follow it. The `$set` part will be more like `$set: { 'profile_image_metadata.$.image_content': None }` but you need to fix the **query**. Read the linked question.

Comment: I just did that. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: To make your model happy that probably really should be `BinData` with something empty rather than `None`. But the general point is updating the matched element.