# Mongoose, more efficient way of searching through array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with Mongoose and MongoDB - and am searching through a nested array in my document for an object with a specified ID.

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
    const dbGuild = guildModel.findById(guildId);
    for (member of dbGuild.guildData.members) {
      if (member._id === mentionedUserId) {
        console.log(member.economy.hand);
        console.log(member.economy.bank);

        member.economy.bank = 5000;
        const updated = await dbGuild.save();
      }
    }
```

Where I am looping through every single value in that array - however this seems very inefficient as it would mean that if there was a large amount of data in the array I would be querying a huge amount of data.

Is it possible to do this on the database? And only return the single object with that id.

Comment: You can find info in this response Update field in exact element array in MongoDB https://stackoverflow.com/a/10433042/4871259

Comment: Take a look at MongoDB [array operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-array/) **OR** you can search through its doc to find any proper operator such as [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and MongoDB [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/aggregation/)

Comment: @AliTavafi
Thanks for your help, however I'm struggling to work out how to implement this? C currently I've got the following:

`
    guildModel.update(
      { "guildData.members._id": guildId },
      { $set: { "guildData.members.$.economy.bank": "new_value" } },
      { multi: true }
    );
`
However, it's not working - I'm likely going about it in completely the wrong way. Any chance you could give me some advice?

Comment: If you are trying to update an array element, based upon a condition, you can do that using the [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/). There are various array update operators and each have a specific purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you have data like that

[image]

if you know the position of element in the array

```
db.roundTest.findAndModify({
       query: { _id : ObjectId('60c916684bd16901f36efb3a') },
       update: { $set: { "holes.$[elem].holeGross" : 8 } },
       arrayFilters: [ { "elem.no": 1 } ]
    })
```

other method to update a single object in the array

```
db.document.update({
       "_id":"idofobject"
    },
   {
     "$set":{
      "holes.$.name" : "Augmon" //you should use name of yourfiled 
   }})
```

for more detail read that article [Update single (same) field in every object of an array](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/update-single-same-field-in-every-object-of-an-array/111447)

watch this video to see how to use these queries [update monogoDB Array Elements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRXjJRJ03_A&ab_channel=MongoDB)

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I don't know the position of the object in the array? That's what I need to search through the array by?

Any chance you could give me some advice as to how I would achieve this?
@SyedAliShahzil

Comment: I hope this would solve your problem. see this video to get experts in updating arrays in MongoDB